# Non-interference engine explanation animation/Videos?

Tags: engine, camry

Non-interference engine explanation animation/Videos ?

I did ask my Toyota dealer about published material on 1999 Camry 2.2 non-interference engine that did not cause piston hitting valves/ valve bent condition during timing belt slipping off spindle event.

**They did not find any. I searched toyota.com , gates.com & alldata nothing showed up.**

Are there any such material exist?

I found the generic piece http://www.samarins.com/glossary/dohc.html

This page, from Gates' website : http://www.gates.com/products/automotive/passenger-car-and-light-truck/timing-system/automotive-timing-belts

It explains only one part,  Interference Engine. Did gates purposefully omit the Free Running explanation?

**Toyota should be proud of explaining about their non-Interference Engine characteristics, but they are shying away in reality.**

Thanks for your comments  update 7/4/2015.

I do see "non-interference (or free running) motor does not have pistons and valves which share the same space - if the cam/valve timing is interrupted, no damage between cam and valve should occur." in various blogs/forums.

**How does a mechanic learn/operate upon it? I did not find this info in repair manual/ALLDATA etc. Is it documented in repair steps?**

Does all non-interference (or free running) motor have same characteristics/behavior ?

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about material showing the difference, but the explanation is pretty easy: an interference motor has pistons and valves which share the same space within the engine at different times - if the cam/valve timing gets interrupted for any reason, **damage between cam and valve *may* occur**; the non-interference (or free running) motor does not have pistons and valves which share the same space - if the cam/valve timing is interrupted, **no damage** between cam and valve *should* occur. (NOTE: There are engines out there which are touted as *non-interference*, but this means no piston to valve interference. These same engines may have *valve to valve* interference. This refers to some of the newer engines, which have DOHC and four valves per cylinder.)